# Perl Got error when use pp -o test.pl

Tags: perl, exe, pp-perl-par-packager

I tried to convert perl program to exe file. My perl version is 5.16.2 on my Windows 7 64bit, I use ppm install PAR:Packer, version 1.013, But when I use pp -o test.pl, I got the error:

> Perl lib version (5.16.2) doesn't match executable version (v5.16.0).

I have googled extensively, but as of yet haven't been able to find a solution, any help is greatly appreciated, thanks a lot!

Comment: I only install once using ppm install PAR::Packer

Answer (score 1):

The build machine where you generated perl executable has the perl version 5.16.0. This perl executable can in turn spawn another perl script. This newly spawned perl script will use the perl 5.16.2 library installed in the host machine thereby leading to the conflict.

PP unpacks the perl executable in the host machine before executing them. If you can prepend your PATH environment variable to that path then PP finds 5.16.0 perl library instead of perl library installed in the host system.